# Create HTML Form & send data to Google-Sheet on submit

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I'm new with Google-Sheet and I didn't use Javascript for a few years.

I'm trying to create a form that can write some data in a sheet. My form looks OK. But when I click the submit button, the form disappear and nothing happens on my sheet. My browser display just an blank tab.

For now, I tried to make work a form with a single input but nothing works. I don't see any error msg in my browser...

I have ( my .gs) :

```js
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTMLForm');
}

function processForm(form) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dEJEuWmG-4Z2geqz9LroTsIbq6LwMSZgVft5uo5vQxw/edit#gid=0";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var x = sheet.getSheetByName("DATA");
  x.appendRow([form.Thing_ID]);
}
```

And my form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>
  function mySubmit(form) {
    google.script.run.processForm(form);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
  </script>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="mySubmit(this)">

        <label>Thing's ID</label>
        <input type="text" id="Thing_ID" placeholder="ID" required/>

        <button type="submit"id="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need that the value I type in the input is written in my spreadsheet (sheet "DATA"). If you could tell me what function I missed/missused.

Thanks